# Include name of belongs_to model object in URL using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo

I want to make seo friendly URLs on a travel site which will not only included the hotel, but also the location as such:

www.domain.com/country-name/destination-name/hotel-name

I've found many example of make pretty urls for the hotel name (using to_param) and wonder how it could be implemented going up the model chain.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code.

config/routes.rb

```
get ':country_name/:destination_name/:hotel_name', to: 'hotels#show'
```

app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_hotel, only: [:show]
    def index
        @hotels = Hotel.all
    end
    def show
    end
    private
        def set_hotel
            @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

app/views/hotels/index.html.erb

```
<% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    <%= hotel.name %>
    <% country = hotel.country.downcase.gsub(" ","-") %>
    <% destination_name = hotel.destination_name.downcase.gsub(" ","-") %>
    <% hotel_name = hotel.name.downcase.gsub(" ","-") %>
    <% @url = "#{country}/#{destination_name}/#{hotel_name}?id=#{hotel.id}" %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', @url %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks great Prashant. I'll give it a try. Thanks!